# AWS Selling Partner API - Export Listings in Product Feed Format

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to update my listings via the SP API and I was wondering if there's a way to export a listing in the expected feed's format in order to reupload the file after the updates. Initially I tried to construct the feed from the response of "getCatalogItem" but not all the data are there so I couldn't.